# How to terminate a child process?

Tags: rust, process

I'm trying to write a small program that runs a child process in background and terminates it if it's not finished after a timeout. Bonus point is that the output of a child should be captured.

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::thread;
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut child_handle = Command::new("/path/to/prog.sh")
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn()
            .expect("could not spawn program");

    println!("CHILD STARTED");

    let mut out = child_handle.stdout.take().expect("could not take stdout");

    let mut thread_handle = Some(thread::spawn(move|| {
        let mut buf = [0;65536];
        let mut all_out: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

        loop {
            println!("reading max 65K bytes");
            match out.read(&mut buf) {
                Ok(sz) => {
                    println!("read {} bytes", sz);
                    all_out.extend_from_slice(&buf[0..sz]);
                },
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("could not read bytes: {}", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }));

    println!("WAITING...");
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2500));

    println!("KILLING");
    child_handle.kill();
    thread_handle.take().unwrap().join();
}
```

While the `prog.sh` is script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1
echo Ready
sleep 1
echo Steady
sleep 10
echo Go
```

Here is what happens: the child programs lasts 12 seconds total, while I try to terminate it after 2.5 seconds. The problem is that for some reason `kill` does not trigger the blocking `read` to terminate with error, and the thread loop exists only after the child exists, and not when it's "killed".

First I tried using a different approach with `Child::wait_with_output`, but I could not find the way to do it: I'm wrapping the child handle to `Arc<Mutex>` (otherwise I cannot share it with the thread, right?), but in order to call `wait_with_output` I have to lock it, this making impossible to concurrently call `kill` on the same locked child. I'm stuck.

Answer (score -2):

Look at this example. It might be helpful for  you

```
use std::process::{Child, Command};

fn main() {
    let child = Command::new("sleep")
        .arg("10")
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to spawn child process");

    // After 10 seconds, terminate the child process.
    let _ = child.kill();
}
```

In this example, we first use the Command struct to create a new child process that will sleep for 10 seconds. Then, we use the spawn method to start the child process. If the child process is successfully started, we store its handle in the child variable.

Finally, we use the kill method to terminate the child process after 10 seconds. The kill method takes a mutable reference to the child process handle as its argument. If the child process is already terminated, the kill method will return an error.

Comment: The real problem is with the thread code blocked during `read` while the child process is already dead. I should've renamed the question title...